# Executing PHP tasks in one directory from another directory

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell

I am working on a project where files are uploaded on a webpage, a copy of the files are 
moved to a new directory where some processing is done by an additional php program and 
a shell script. The php program calls the shell script. This all works fine when I call
the php file from the command line while in that directory. When I try to call the 
php program from the upload web page in the other directory the processing is not done.

Essentially, php file A in directory A copies the uploaded files to directory B where php file B processes them and generates a graph. File A copies the files properly. And when I call file B from the command line while in directory B, file B works as well. It is calling file B from file A and having it execute/write to directory B that does not seem to work.

I would be happy to include any code if necessary.

So far I have attempted to execute file B with a shell script called at the end of file A which would

```
    cd directoryB 
    php fileB.php
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

It looks like file B might be beginning to execute, but not completing. The page displays 'Stack Trace:' but no additional information.

Comment: Please elaborate the problem - do you get any errors (is error reporting turned on)?

Comment: There are no error messages in the apache error log. I did an edit above with a little more information.

Comment: You may have overlooked this when asking the question: `We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research`. (Its written right to the "Ask a question" text area).

Comment: Well hard to help with so few details, but a possible cause could be php max_execution_time, which is unlimited for CLI but usually limited for server. Try to increase the value in php.ini

Comment: My guess is in your script B you have hardcoded relative paths to files/directories to process. You think they're relative to the script's location, but they're actually relative to current working directory so they become invalid if the script is executed from outside directory B.

Comment: Try using absolute path.

Comment: Have you checked that the webserver accout has rights to access and execute a script in these other directories?